# Encode The Particular columns in a Table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

There's some sensitive data which I want to store in the table. 
I already have a table in the DB. What I want to do is add 2 new columns in the existing table and use some encoding on those 2 columns so that original value will not be displayed directly.
Could anyone help how can I proceed on this?

Comment: Start here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/encryption/encrypt-a-column-of-data

Comment: Thanks @JacobH. As mentioned in the above link, data needs to be stored somewhere in original format before we encrypt it. 
Can't I encrypt the data directly while I am inserting data into a table without storing it in the original format also without creating any trigger on the table.

Comment: Yes, by using the [encryptbykey](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/encryptbykey-transact-sql) function

Comment: This tutorial may help as well: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2431/sql-server-column-level-encryption-example-using-symmetric-keys/